# How can I allow all urls to public/

Tags: node.js, express

I have some translation files, and I want to fetch this, but I dont know how can I allow the URL in nodejs express ?

This url I fetch

```
http://192.168.0.249:4000/public/locales/{{lng}}/translation.json
```

So how can I say allow all urls in public folder?

like

```
app.get('*/public') ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the express.static built-in middleware:

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

See: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: thanks but I have a translation.js file: public/locales/de/translation.js, if I enter the url then I get can not get translation.js

Comment: Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL. So http://192.168.0.249:4000/locales/de/translation.json should work when using the above express static expression.

Comment: Or if you want to keep the url intact you can use `app.use('/public', express.static('public'))`. Then  http://192.168.0.249:4000/public/locales/de/translation.json should work.